# How can I use different codes for different screen sizes?

Tags: android, configuration

I am developing android program that have a lot of supported screen sizes and I have different layout for each screen , but some layout have extra buttons and views so I want to change the code according to the current used device for example when I use tablet I want to use different main.java code 
how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a value in the res folder for that:

```
- values-large
    * booleans.xml
- values
    * booleans.xml
```

Each booleans.xml should have a different value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>    
</resources>
```

Instead of a boolean "isTablet", you can separate by sizes depending on what you need. You can then get this value and use it in your code:

```
public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
    return context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
}
```

Comment: I used down vote without intent , I want to use up vote please edit your answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to check for different screen size in your activity and then use appropriate xml for that. following code may work

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    final int height=dm.heightPixels;
    final int width=dm.widthPixels;

    if(width == 720 || width==1280 && height == 1280 || height==720)    //galaxy s3
    {
      //code to select xml file
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either u use fragmentation in android for satisfying ur condition...or you can include the line to detect the screen size in yoor code and if a particular screen size is found,u can hav the extra buttons(or anything else) connected

Answer (score 0):

To detect the screen dimensions use [`DisplayMetrics`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html):

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

Nexy ou can use `metrics.widthPixels` and/or `metrics.heightPixels` (or any other field that is useful to you) in your code to react on different screen sizes:

```
if(metrics.widthPixels >= 500) {
  // Support code for additional buttons at a width of 500 and larger
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get screen size use:

```
public static double getScreenSize(WindowManager windowManager) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics( metrics ); 
        float widthInInches = metrics.widthPixels / metrics.densityDpi; 
        float heightInInches = metrics.heightPixels / metrics.densityDpi;

        return  Math.sqrt(Math.pow(widthInInches,2) + Math.pow(heightInInches,2));
    }
```

To determine is tablet:

```
public final static double TABLET_SIZE = 5.0; //inch

    public static boolean IsTablet(WindowManager windowManager) {
        double inch = getScreenSize(windowManager);             
        return inch >= TABLET_SIZE;
    }
```

To determine if portrait orientation:

```
public static boolean isPortraitOrientation(Context context) {
    context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    return context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
}
```